# Make a text string fill left, then right

Tags: html, css

So I have been trying all day to get this to work, but now I'm questioning if it's even possible..

[image: Image 1]

I basically want to allow the string "Sugar" to expand to the left and fill up, then head to the right; when a longer text string is inputted. Allowing me to keep a similar appearance to the design.

[image: Image 2]

I'm now guessing that this isn't going to be possible with just css on its own?

My code currently looks like this:

```css
#air_track {
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 24px 0 0 30px;
}
#air_track-span-1 {
  font-family: GothamBlack;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 900;
  float: left;
}
#air_track-span-2 {
  font-family: GothamBook;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="air_track">
  <span id="air_track-span-1">Maroon 5</span>
  <br />
  <span id="air_track-span-2">Sugar</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean? You want to have some padding on the left when the word is short enough, and no padding when the word is longer?

Comment: The code you gave looks correct, or at least as I understand it. http://jsfiddle.net/omuosrqt/

Comment: @tribe84 so it does.. although the original of mine still bugs out and drops down a line. Looking at your fiddle you've added a clearfix which seems to resolve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, but this should give you an idea on how to apporch it with jquery. I don't think there is a pure css way to do it.

1. .each = find all tag that have class name of title,
2. el.width = find the width of that title
3. el.next.width = find the next el which should be subtitle...
4. if statment = compare the title width with subtitle width

than you can use .css to change the stylesheet.

```
$('.title').each(
    function(index, el) {
         thisWidth = $(el).width();
         subTitleWidth = $(el).next().width();
         if(thisWidth>subTitleWidth) {
              // align right 
         } else {
              // align left
         }   

    }
);
```